# How to fix blank Woocommerce Dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've installed WooCommerce on my WordPress website.

When I click on WooCommerce -> Dashboard, it flashes some store information ( orders, revenue, profit...etc) and quickly disappears within a second. On checking the console errors, it shows:

> TypeError: "this.style is undefined"

I approached the WooCommerce team, but they failed to sort it out.
Please help to eliminate this error.

Comment: ¿have you tried to disable your plugins? ¿that is all the info you have?

Comment: Please try to uninstall and reinstall the plugin. Also try disabling any backend themese you might have installed.